# How to import a random model from DB in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

Currently trying to teach myself Django and in doing so I am trying to recreate the popular Wordle game. To start I created a Model named 'Words' which contains 5 letter words. I am trying to generate one of those random words into my views.py where I can then have the user start attempting to guess the word. This is my first time asking a question in stack overflow so I will try and display what I have so far the best I can.

Currently in my:

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Words

def home(request):
    word = random.choice(Words)
    context = {'word', word}

    return render(request,'home.html', context)
```

----- I understand `word = random.choice(Words)` is not possible, What is the best way to do this?

Models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Words(models.Model):
    word = models.CharField(max_length=5)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.word
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A straightforward, but non-optimal way would be:

```py
Words.objects.order_by("?").first()
```

This operation can be heavy if you have a lot of rows in the DB table, since it does `ORDER BY` on the entire table without using any index.

A better way of choosing a random model is along the lines of:

```py
def get_random_word():
    max_id = Word.objects.all().aggregate(max_id=Max('pk'))['max_id']
    while True:
        pk = random.randint(1, max_id)
        word = Word.objects.filter(pk=pk).first()
        if word:
            return word
```

What this does is:

1. Find the largest row ID (assuming that the ID is a surrogate auto-incrementing integer)
2. Get a random number between 1 and the largest row ID
3. Try to select the row at that ID

The loop is needed if you have holes in the numbering, for example if you've deleted a row.

See [this post](https://books.agiliq.com/projects/django-orm-cookbook/en/latest/random.html) for more details.